# How to improve query performance of OR using timestamp comparison?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I have a PostgreSQL table contain around 30 million records, and I'm trying to find records that have a boolean flag set or have a timestamp field older than a certain date.

So I'm running a query like:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM "mytable" WHERE (NOT "fresh" OR "updated" <= '2021-12-15');
```

I've created a conditional index for the `fresh` column, and well as `updated`. But this query still takes over an hour to run.

Running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query gives me:

```
"Finalize Aggregate  (cost=16776135.69..16776135.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=823617.787..823622.881 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=16776135.47..16776135.68 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=823617.402..823622.875 rows=3 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=16775135.47..16775135.48 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=823610.692..823610.693 rows=1 loops=3)"
"              ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable  (cost=198534.00..16764121.82 rows=4405460 width=4) (actual time=2294.720..823168.522 rows=3466344 loops=3)"
"                    Recheck Cond: ((NOT fresh) OR (updated <= '2021-12-15 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))"
"                    Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 4039989"
"                    Filter: ((NOT fresh) OR (updated <= '2021-12-15 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))"
"                    Heap Blocks: exact=10713 lossy=1578169"
"                    ->  BitmapOr  (cost=198534.00..198534.00 rows=10544896 width=0) (actual time=2280.370..2280.372 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mytable_fresh  (cost=0.00..4.83 rows=72 width=0) (actual time=16.200..16.200 rows=46375 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (fresh = false)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mytable_updated_734dc8aa  (cost=0.00..193242.62 rows=10544824 width=0) (actual time=2264.168..2264.169 rows=10357399 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (updated <= '2021-12-15 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)"
"Planning Time: 4.520 ms"
"Execution Time: 3823622.946 ms"
```

So it's using the indexes, but they don't seem to have much of an effect.

What else can I do to improve performance of this query?

Comment: You should post the table and index DDL statements. Do you know you can create an index on more than one column?

Comment: Increase work_mem until `lossy=...` goes away.  If it is still slow, then turn on track_io_timing and show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`

Comment: turning  count(id) into count(*) could also help, a little or maybe a lot, depending on version.  But only once you increase work_mem

Comment: Notice that executing the query only consumed 20% of the turn around time witnessed by the client software.  The other 80% was *probably* spent waiting on a lock before the query execution proper could even start.

Comment: @mustaccio Yes, I created an index on both columns, but the explain didn't show it being used and it didn't improve query speed.

Comment: @jjanes Is there any way around that? There are a lot of clients writing and reading from the database (leans more towards reads), so not really any time when someone won't be locking the table. However, for my purposes, I don't need to wait for locks to get an exact count. An estimate will do.

Comment: Ordinary queries shouldn't be locking the table in a way that would cause that.  So the first step would be verify my hypothesis, for example by turning on log_lock_waits to see if long waits are even occurring.  This would also show you what type of lock it was on. (But you should also repeat this several times to see if the big difference in the two ways of measuring time are reproducible.)

Comment: did you try a partial index? `create index on ... (updated) where not fresh`?